# tmux copy mouse selected text to clipboard automatically on mouse release

Tags: tmux

I only use mouse text selection in tmux terminal to get the text to clipboard.

Can I configure tmux to put the just selected text into system clipboard automatically after the mouse button is released, so I am then able to paste the text with Ctrl-v in some other application like firefox?

Comment: That's what happens anyway?

Comment: I clarified it a bit what is not working for me.

Comment: There is software that merges the two clipboards. Never used one myself, but maybe you can google for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that since tmux 2.2 we can bind a command to MouseDragEnd1Pane event.

So this one line in `~/.tmux.conf` configures tmux to copy the mouse selected text to the system clipboard automatically after mouse button is released:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "xclip -in -selection clipboard"
```

Comment: I added this line but it works only in tmux. How can I copy line to paste in firefox (for example)?

Comment: Hmm, it works for me, I can paste the value in any application.

Comment: Since `tmux 2.4` the command is a bit different `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard"`

Comment: `bind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xsel -b'` worked as well, using shorthands and an [alternative](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) tool.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using tmux 2.5 in iTerm2 on OSX Sierra, and this works for me:

```
unbind -T copy-mode MouseDragEnd1Pane
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

If you don't want to cancel the selection, you can use `copy-pipe` instead of `copy-pipe-and-cancel`.

See also [reattach-to-user-namespace on Github](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard).

Comment: I've been using `copy-pipe-and-cancel` for years and really I wanted `copy-pipe`